# Android - Force fetching new gcm-messages

Tags: android, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently developing a titanium app that uses the gcm.js module to handle GCM messages. But GCM seems to be really buggy when it comes to message delivery. It happens very often that I get the messages with a delay of several hours, if they are received at all.

I know that GCM tries to save energy. But strangely, GCM is the most unreliable, when the phone is connected to my computer via USB, and I am debugging the app. In my opinion, GCM should not try to save energy in this case at all! Notifications should arrive immediately, when the phone is currently charging.

I've event tried to send the messaged with a TTL value of 0-10, to make use of the "now or never" effect, but this only resulted in never getting any messages.

So, what I need is a way to manually force my android phone to fetch new GCM messages, so that I can debug what happens when I receive them. I don't have the time to wait hours until the phone receives the message.

Is there a way to do this?

PS: Yes, I've tried several phones, including Nexus 5, Galaxy Nexus and some htc devices. Everywhere the same :/

Comment: Has it occurred to you that it's not GCM which is buggy and the problem is with Titanium / Javascript?

Comment: @Squonk it of course is a possibility, but I doubt it, since the receiving part is written in Java, which does not get the notification, I think. I've also tried another gcm-module that had a completely different codebase for fetching gcm notifications, which worked also, but with the same delay and unreliability, which was the reason I switched over to gcm.js. So I really doubt that the problem is the gcm module. It's the whole gcm system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (just for debugging purposes):
1) Make sure `delay_while_idle` flag is set to `false` (wouldn't advice to keep it as false in final product).
2) Keep TTL as is.
3) Use message with payload (remember the limit is 4 kb). You can set this by removing `collapse_key` parameter.
4) Now implement [message_type](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#getMessageType(android.content.Intent)) in your receiver.

My logic here is that you send a message with proper payload and since its going to live for only 10 seconds, it will collapse. Once collapsed, through `message_type_deleted` you can fetch that message. (Sync app to fetch)

PS: I doubt this will be a stable technique but it will serve the purpose most likely.

Hopefully it helped!